# Can't fix image orientation on mobile input

Tags: javascript, exif

This code used to work on iPhone 8, and won't work on iPhone 12 `Chrome`.

The image will be wrongly rotated 90 degrees after I select it from Photos on iPhone using `input` and rotate it before show.

```
  getOrientation(input,function(orientation){
      resetOrientation(base64, orientation, function(resetBase64Image){


        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
        ..... // here we get the image
```

and the functions that do the job :

```
function getOrientation(file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {

        var view = new DataView(e.target.result);
        if (view.getUint16(0, false) != 0xFFD8)
        {
            return callback(-2);
        }
        var length = view.byteLength, offset = 2;
        while (offset < length)
        {
            if (view.getUint16(offset+2, false) <= 8) return callback(-1);
            var marker = view.getUint16(offset, false);
            offset += 2;
            if (marker == 0xFFE1)
            {
                if (view.getUint32(offset += 2, false) != 0x45786966)
                {
                    return callback(-1);
                }

                var little = view.getUint16(offset += 6, false) == 0x4949;
                offset += view.getUint32(offset + 4, little);
                var tags = view.getUint16(offset, little);
                offset += 2;
                for (var i = 0; i < tags; i++)
                {
                    if (view.getUint16(offset + (i * 12), little) == 0x0112)
                    {
                        return callback(view.getUint16(offset + (i * 12) + 8, little));
                    }
                }
            }
            else if ((marker & 0xFF00) != 0xFF00)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                offset += view.getUint16(offset, false);
            }
        }
        return callback(-1);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}




function resetOrientation(srcBase64, srcOrientation, callback) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
    var width = img.width,
            height = img.height,
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // set proper canvas dimensions before transform & export
        if (4 < srcOrientation && srcOrientation < 9) {
        canvas.width = height;
      canvas.height = width;
    } else {
        canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
    }

    // transform context before drawing image
        switch (srcOrientation) {
      case 2: ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1, width, 0); break;
      case 3: ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, -1, width, height ); break;
      case 4: ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, height ); break;
      case 5: ctx.transform(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0); break;
      case 6: ctx.transform(0, 1, -1, 0, height , 0); break;
      case 7: ctx.transform(0, -1, -1, 0, height , width); break;
      case 8: ctx.transform(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, width); break;
      default: break;
    }

        // draw image
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // export base64
        callback(canvas.toDataURL());
  };

    img.src = srcBase64;
}
```

Is there any stable simple way to do this for every iPhone ?

Comment: Most likely there is not any stable way. Your code would need to actually understand the image to orientate it correctly (so, that it looks correct with human eyes), you can't rely on the orientation data the image (possibly) contains.

Comment: @Teemu thanks so how should i "understand" the image ?

Comment: Well, you know, ex. an image of face, you know exactly how it should be orientated, but your code will blindly orientate such an image upside down, if the data says so. The most problematic images are those taken downwards (ex. towards a floor), the orientation sensors can't know the correct position, and the result is totally random.

Comment: not sure really what you are saying, to understand photo you have only exif, or using AI. Which is you mean ?

Comment: AI mostly, like said, you can't trust the exif data. Depending on where you're getting the images, they might not contain exif data at all (ex. many server-side image handlers remove the exif data).

Comment: So in order to show a user a thumbnail of his input image, i have to do AI on mobile? or upload to server and then do AI ? i have a feeling no serious company do those things. I can let the user to flip it as he like. but i still think we are missing something here :)

Comment: "_we are missing something here_". Definitely yes! You never said where your images are coming from, you just wanted to automatically orient some images correctly. Now it appears, that those images are user input, and you've also solved your problem ("_let the user to flip it_"). What comes to the use of AI, "serious companies" (ex. Google) really use it to handle bunches of images, catecorizing images based on the content, and most likely also to find the correct orientatation.

Comment: Where can my images comes from, if i upload them on an iPhone? maybe... the iPhone gallery ? ( which is the only allowed way on iOS). We most likely missed something, because i am testing many websites on mobile, for instance Airbnb, which allow you to easily upload photos and show the right orientation using no AI (instantly on mobile).

Answer (score 1):

Well after lots of testing, turns out that something changed, and now you **don't** have to rotate the image when you *preview it*, only when you save it to your server.

Tested on `iOS 13, 14`, on multiple iPhones, `Chrome` and `Safari`.

When you preview the photo first time, Apple knows where the photo comes from and knows it's orientation, so it show it in the right way, but when you show a photo from a server - they don't, so then they use the exif.